# Showing that a differentiable function is increasing and bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$
and $|f'(x)|\leqslant L$

Let $g(x)=f(x)+Lx$

Show that $g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is increaing and bounded on $(a,b)$.

Consider $x_{1},x_{2}\in(a,b)$ where $x_{1}<x_{2}$.

Now $g(x_{1})=f(x_{1})+Lx_{1}$

$g(x_{2})=f(x_{2})+Lx_{2}$

Now $g(x_{2})-g(x_{1})=f(x_{2})+Lx_{2}-f(x_{1})-Lx_{1}$

$g(x_{2})-g(x_{1})=f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})-L(x_{1}-x_{2})$

Show that $f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})\geqslant L(x_{1}-x_{2})$

$\frac{f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\leqslant L\iff f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})\leqslant L(x_{2}-x_{1})$

Any hints on where to go next?

Comment: Hint: try understanding more about $f$ first: specifically, show that $f$ is bounded on $(a, b)$ (using the mean value theorem). This gives you that $g$ is bounded on $(a, b)$. Then show that $g'$ is non-negative so that $g$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

We have $-L\le f'\le L.$ Thus, since $g'=f'+L,$ we see $0\le g'\le 2L.$

i) $0\le g'$ implies $g$ is increasing, by the MVT.

ii) Fix $x_0\in (a,b).$  Then for any $x\in (a,b),$ $$g(x)=g(x)-g(x_0)+g(x_0) = g'(c_x)(x-x_0) + g(x_0)$$ by the MVT. This implies $|g(x)|\le L|x-x_0| + |g(x_0)| \le L(b-a)+|g(x_0)|$ for any $x\in (a,b).$ Hence $g$ is bounded on $(a,b).$